# No suitable peers available on main with light client

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a Ethereum node running in light mode. When I was developing on Rinkeby, everything was running fine, but as soon as I changed to mainnet, I began to have issues with "no suitable peers available". I'm getting that a lot now.

As far as I understand I need to connect to a full node (peer) to send transactions to the blockchain, but do you guys know any good way to ensure a solid connection to mainnet blockchain?

Comment: Here is a list of peers: https://gist.github.com/rfikki/e2a8c47f4460668557b1e3ec8bae9c11